# bubble sort in java without using function?

Tags: java

I want to make bubble sort program but without using any function

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [] a={98,87,42,12,42,63,56,11};
        for(int i=0;i<a.length-1;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<a.length-i-1;j++){
                if(a[j]>a[j+1]){
                    int temp=a[j+1];
                    a[j]=a[j+1];
                    a[j+1]=temp;
                }
                
            }
            System.out.println(a[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

anyone guide me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please post what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you want to switch a[j] and a[j+1] so tempt should be a[j]

`System.out.println(a[i]);` the pringing should be outside of the loops after all the switching is done

this should work

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [] a={98,87,42,12,42,63,56,11};
        for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<a.length-i-1;j++){
                if(a[j]>a[j+1]){
                    int temp=a[j];
                    a[j]=a[j+1];
                    a[j+1]=temp;
                }
            }
        }
        for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
            System.out.print(a[i] + " ");
        }
    }
```